# How do I clone a Google Colab environment to a local Anaconda environment on Windows?

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory

I have a notebook that works fine in Google Colab.  I am not able to properly create an Anaconda environment with the packages due to dependency issues.  Is there a way to install all required packages from colab to local Windows Anaconda environment?  Using pip freeze gives a list that is appropriate for Linux but not for windows

Answer (score 4):

In google Colab, run the following code:

```
!pip freeze >> requierements.txt
```

All the packages that were installed will appear here to be downloaded

[image]

Later on, on your localhost run,

```
pip install -r requierements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohana 
I did the job using this command **!python -m pip freeze > requierements.txt**